# Is there any reference about Ergodic Theorems applicable to stochastic processes with strong dependence?

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, ergodic

Consider the stochastic process $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}} = (A^{+}_{n},A^{-}_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined over the same probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},\mathbb{P})$ such that the occurrence of the state $X_{n + 1} = (A^{+}_{n + 1},A^{-}_{n + 1})$ depends on the occurrence of $X_{n} = (A^{+}_{n},A^{-}_{n})$, $X_{n - 1} = (A^{+}_{n - 1},A^{-}_{n - 1})$ and so on until $X_{0} = (A^{+}_{0},A^{-}_{0})$, where $A^{+}_{n}$ and $A^{-}_{n}$ are recursively defined as follows:

\begin{align*}
A^{-}_{n+1} & := \left\{\ell\in\mathbb{Z}_{<0} \mid \min(A_{n}) - \max_{k\in A_{n}}\{R_{k} - (k - \min(A_{n}))\}\leq \ell < \min(A_{n})\right\}\\\\
A^{+}_{n+1} & := \left\{\ell\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0} \mid \max(A_{n}) < \ell \leq \max(A_{n}) + \displaystyle\max_{k\in A_{n}}\{R_{k} - (\max(A_{n}) - k)\}\right\}
\end{align*}

where $A^{-}_{0} = A^{+}_{0} = A_{0} = \{0\}$, $A_{n} = A^{-}_{n}\cup A^{+}_{n}$ and $(R_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a sequence of IID random variables such that $R_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$.

Comment: davidson's "stochastic limit theory" has material on ergodicity and dependence and mixing but I can't say it has material on your problem. I don't understand what you are doing but it looks extremely specific and complex so I would tend to doubt it. but it's worth checking out to see.